# Install SSL certificate when request generated on another server

Tags: ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

I have a new SSL certificate to install (IIS7) but when I do complete certificate request I get  'Cannot find the certificate request associated with this certificate file. A certificate request must be completed on the computer where the request was created'. The request was generated on 123-reg and not on the server. I have a .pem and public and private keys from 123-reg but I don't know what to do with them to get them installed on the server so I can complete the request!

Can anyone point me in the right direction please :)

Comment: did you ever solve this? 123-reg seem like cowboys who don't explain anything...

Comment: I contacted their support and they said to generate a new CSR from the server and send it to them and they'll generate a new ticket. I did also try creating a PKCS(12) file using an online tool that I found which would enable me to import the CSR into IIS but it kept giving me an error. I'm not sure what the point of 123-reg allowing you to generate a CSR from their website is if you can't then install the certificate on your server, and you're right, they didn't offer any explanation!

Comment: thanks - yeah they really don't think their support through, lack of intelligence all round...

Comment: Ha yes it seems to be a common problem with support. They initially didn't bother reading my support ticket and just sent me a link with instructions on how to install a certificate. I had to get stroppy before they actually listened to what I had initially told them - that I was unable to install the certificate!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a certificate request you also get a CSR file with the request which is sent to the certification authority.

Read [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file) for a full explanation of all files involved in the certification process.

In your case it seems that the server is complaining maybe because your domain does not match the  input you provided the certificate request. Maybe your CSR is configured for mydomain.com but IIS is configured for somthing like localhost or an IP. Check that out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply and for the link. I'm still none the wiser though. My CSR was not generated on the server where I'm trying to complete the request. I don't know enough about IIS and certificates to go any further, I pretty much know how to complete a certificate request!